# Why traditional python gets preference over anaconda python in cmd when path of former is set to system and latter is set to user env variables?

Tags: python, windows, windows-10, anaconda, environment-variables

I added traditional python to path in System Environment Variables.
Then I installed Anaconda Python and added that to User Environment Variables.
Now when I check packages using pip list, it lists packages for the traditional python and when i remove traditional python from path, and enter pip list, it lists packages from anaconda python. So why does system variable python get preference and what will i have to do to use both pythons at the same time according to my choice using different commands ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why not use just Anaconda Python or just regular Python?

Comment: I am new to all this stuff. So i wanted to keep traditional python so as if i mess up working with anaconda python i can switch back to traditional one.

Comment: I would suggest you pick one and stick with it. If you need to switch to the other, you should only have that one copy of Python on your computer. Otherwise, you will always be confused about which one you're using.

Comment: Okay. I'll do that. Thanks @darthbith .
But can you still explain what's actually going on here with the environment variables and python distribution ?

Comment: Nope, I can't. Sorry :-) You'd be better off asking specifically about the User vs. System environment variables on SuperUser I think, but you don't need to frame it as an Anaconda question, you could find out whether the same effect occurs if you want to use some other environment information.